# Magento - Cart Price Rules Quantity Issue

Tags: cart-rule, magento-1.5, price-rules

Ok so I have a really puzzling problem which I can't seem to get past, I think my logic is flawed.

We're providing combination deals such as:

3 items = 2% Off
4 items = 4% Off
5 items = 6% Off
6 items = 8% Off

Now I've got this working fine up to now but I have one main problem which is stopping me from continuing with the project. The problem is for example:

A customer adds 4 separate items to the basket and they get the 4% discount. But on the last minute they decide change the quantity of one of the 4 items to 2. Now when they change the quantity of one of the items to 2, the discount reverts back to 2% but for the cost of the 5 items.

When adding 3 items they get 2% discount and if they change the quantity it keeps the discount the exact same, so the first rule works fine, but anything above the 3 items combo rule is messes up.

Any help at all would be amazing help for me.

Thanks a lot guys.

Note: Try it to see exactly my situation: http://bathroomcouture.co.uk/testserver

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your problem correctly, but try to use "Stop further rules from processing".
I mean set the priorities of the rules as :

- 6 items = 8% Off - priority 1
- 5 items = 6% Off - priority 2
- 4 items = 4% Off - priority 3
- 3 items = 2% Off - priority 4.

For all the rules set "Stop further rules from processing" to `Yes`.

If that doesn't work, maybe you should add the way these rules are built (or at least one of them) to your question.

Comment: Thanks got the reply.

I've tried to "Stop Further Rules from Processing" on all of them, but for some reason when the quantity is changed the rules is removed and it set to the rule below it.

It's a very awkward discount process but should be simple really, as its only discount added to a set amount of items when added to basket.

Can't seem to find any extension that can help with this either.

It's not looking good is it. :(